# All markdown cells are untrusted

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter-lab, trust

When I create a new notebook in Jupyter Lab, add a line of code, shift-enter, the code runs, produces output and a new cell appears below the first line of code.
The trust shield icon then changes from a check mark to an 'x'.  If I delete the blank cell, the trust icon returns to check mark.

So far so good, blank cells are untrusted, even after saving.

But if instead of deleting the blank cell, I change it to markdown and enter text and save the notebook (say as testTrust.ipynb), the trust icon remains 'x'.  Hovering over the shield icon gives the text: Notebook not trusted, 1 of 2 cells trusted. In a longer notebook, every markdown cell is counted as untrusted.

Running

```
jupyter trust testTrust.ipynb
```

gives

```
ERROR | Notebook missing: testTrust.ipynb
```

This is a new install in a new virtual environment, installed through miniconda:

```
    conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab nodejs ipympl
```

where inclusion of the nodejs package was triggered by a previous install attempt giving:

```
Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
```

at launch, and ipympl was included for use of %matplotlib widgets magic.

How can I fix the trust issues in this install?

Ubuntu 20.04,
python 3.9.2,
jupyterlab 3.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/security.html which explains the security in iPython noteebook.
As mentioned in the article, one of the option to make html text as trusted is to explicitly mark it trusted by executing the following line in command-line

> ipython trust /path/to/notebook.ipynb

Comment: ipython trust <path to notebook> gave deprecation warning but completed without error.  New notebooks added in jupyter lab continue to show markdown as untrusted.  jupyter trust <path to notebook> also completes but effects no change in markdown behavior.